FireBase analytics xamariin forms
I am trying to use firebase analytics for xamatir forms, but any tutorial I found is outdated.
I already created a firebase project, download the json and the firebase crashanalytics is working fine. Now for the firebase analytics in the same project i installed the Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics nugget version 121.3.0.5 in the Android project. I am using xamarin forms 5.0.0.2578. I have the interface:
    public interface IFirebaseAnalyticsService
    {
        void LogEvent(string eventId);
        void LogEvent(string eventId, string paramName, string value);
        void LogEvent(string eventId, IDictionary<string, string> parameters);
        void SetUserId(string userId);
    }

and the class:
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Soft1.Droid.Services;
using Soft1.Droid.Services.Dialogs;
using Soft1.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FirebaseAnalyticsService))]
namespace Soft1.Droid.Services
{
    public class FirebaseAnalyticsService : IFirebaseAnalyticsService
    {
        public void LogEvent(string eventId)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, null);
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, string paramName, string value)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {paramName, value}
        });
        }

        public void SetUserId(string userId)
        {

        var fireBaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity);

        fireBaseAnalytics.SetUserId(userId);

        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {

        var fireBaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity);

        if (parameters == null)
        {
            fireBaseAnalytics.LogEvent(eventId, null);
            return;
        }

        var bundle = new Android.OS.Bundle();

        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            bundle.PutString(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        fireBaseAnalytics.LogEvent(eventId, bundle);

        }
    }
}

In the mainactivity i declare
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
and then in the create method :
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);
Inside my project i tried:
IFirebaseAnalyticsService service = DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAnalyticsService>();
service.LogEvent("login event", "paramname1", "111");

I do not get any erros but in the firebase project console i do not get any updates. I tried also with the debugView, run : adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app **testappname  **, but with no success.
